# Error or bug when switching CSS classes by JavaScript when dragging with mouse

Tags: javascript, css

Ok, here a simple code, which changes td class when you click on them:

```js
const btn = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
btn.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  
  let cells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
  
  for (let i=0; i<cells.length; i++) {
    cells[i].classList = ""
  };
  
  CounterCells();
})





const tabl = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
tabl.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  
  if (event.target.classList == ""){
    event.target.classList.add("green");
    console.log("Nothing to green");
    
  } else if (event.target.classList.contains("white")){
    event.target.classList.replace("white", "green");
    console.log("White to green");
    
  } else if (event.target.classList.contains("green")){
    event.target.classList.replace("green", "red");
    console.log("Green to red");
    
  } else if (event.target.classList.contains("red")) {
    event.target.classList.replace("red", "white");
    console.log("Red to white");
  }
  
  CounterCells();

})







function CounterCells() {
  let cells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
  
  let countWhites = 0;
  let countGreens = 0;
  let countReds = 0;
  
  for (let i=0; i<cells.length; i++) {
    if (cells[i].classList == "") {
      countWhites++
    }
    if (cells[i].classList.contains("white")) {
      countWhites++
    }
    if (cells[i].classList.contains("green")) {
      countGreens++
    }
    if (cells[i].classList.contains("red")) {
      countReds++
    }
  }
  
  const p = document.getElementById("demo");
  p.innerHTML = "Whites: "+countWhites+"<br> Greens: "+countGreens+"<br> Reds: "+countReds;
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.white {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Reset">

<br>
<br>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

If you click it -- anything works fine, but now try to click on cell number one and drag mouse over cell number three and then release mouse button -- class will be assigned to tr not to last td number 3.

Why is that?

https://jsfiddle.net/foxnadir/Ls6p7j1z/3/

Comment: _"strange things will happen"_ - What are we supposed to do with this "explanation"? -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> _"Describe the problem. "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question."_

Comment: Ok, I realized now that it keeps happening because of when you drag the mouse over 1 to 3 -- CSS class assigned not to td's but tr! How to avoid that?

Comment: I don't think its a problem with tr(s), you see this when you drag across columns too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code was that you were attaching the `click` event to the table element, when only one td can be clicked at a time.

I also changed the event from `click` to `mousedown` so that when the user drags from 1 to 3, 1 changes color, but if this behavior is not what you wanted, you can change it back.

Here is the working code:

```js
const btn = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
btn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {

  let cells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

  for (let i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    cells[i].classList = ""
  };

  CounterCells();
})

let cells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

for (i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
  cells[i].addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {

    if (event.target.classList == "") {
      event.target.classList.add("green");
      console.log("Nothing to green");

    } else if (event.target.classList.contains("white")) {
      event.target.classList.replace("white", "green");
      console.log("White to green");

    } else if (event.target.classList.contains("green")) {
      event.target.classList.replace("green", "red");
      console.log("Green to red");

    } else if (event.target.classList.contains("red")) {
      event.target.classList.replace("red", "white");
      console.log("Red to white");
    }

    CounterCells();

  })
}

function CounterCells() {

  let countWhites = 0;
  let countGreens = 0;
  let countReds = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    if (cells[i].classList == "") {
      countWhites++
    }
    if (cells[i].classList.contains("white")) {
      countWhites++
    }
    if (cells[i].classList.contains("green")) {
      countGreens++
    }
    if (cells[i].classList.contains("red")) {
      countReds++
    }
  }

  const p = document.getElementById("demo");
  p.innerHTML = "Whites: " + countWhites + "<br> Greens: " + countGreens + "<br> Reds: " + countReds;
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

tr {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

td {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.white {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Reset">

<br>
<br>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: _"you were attaching the click event to the table element"_ - That's event delegation and reduces the amount of event handlers that would all do the same thing. You just have to add some sanity checks in the event handler in case of event delegation.